# iphone--how to use checkmark to filter the information?

Tags: iphone

I know how to add **checkmark** into the tableview, but the question is how to use **checkmark** to **filter** the information? That means if i have checked item-1, in the table view or view just display the related information about item-1. Anyone can help me or tell me some related tutorial~ Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach:

- Register an action for your checkmark (not sure how you've implemented it but if it's, say, a `UIButton`, use the `addTarget` method)
- In the method that gets called when you click the checkmark, modify the data source so that it's filtered to what you want to display
- Call `[self.tableView reloadData]` to have the `UITableViewController` reload its `tableView` object

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My supervisor suggest me to use Sqlite and FMBD method, but I'm not sure how to apply these method into my project???  Anyway, thank you so much~~

Comment: Sure no problem. But regardless of what you do use, you still need to call `[self.tableView reloadData]` to have the `tableView` call its delegate methods to retrieve data for the cells. Best of luck :)

Comment: Yes, what you said is correct. At hte last part, i need to use this method. Now, i'm still need to learn how to use Sqlite to save data and get data from it~~thanks you so much..May i add you MSN~~my MSN is <funny.mu@live.com.sg> ~~ Btw, Merry Christmas.